# Conditional probability of selecting day in a months

Tags: probability

> A year is chosen at random from  a set of numbers $\{ 2012,2013,\dots,2021 \}$. From the chosen year, a month is chosen at random and from the chosen months, a day is chosen at random. Given that the chosen day is the $29^{\mathrm{th}}$  of the months, the conditional probability that the chosen months is February equal to?

Probability of selecting a year from leap year as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}$ or probability of non-leap year as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{7}$

And probability of selecting a months from $12$ months as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{12}$

And selecting a day in a february month as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{28}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{1}{29}$ whether is is leap year or ñon leap year.

So required probability of selecting

a day in february months as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{12}\cdot \frac{1}{29}+\frac{1}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{12}\cdot \frac{1}{29}$

But my answer is wrong, help me

Comment: It seems like you're on roughly the right track but making mistakes with the details. What's the probability of selecting Feb. 29, 2021? (Hint: there was no such day.) Also, remember that $P(A|B)=P(A,B)/P(B)$. Are you using that? Do you know what $A$ and $B$ should be here?

Comment: @Karl Very good catch.  I totally overlooked that consideration.  So, I have deleted my answer.  Turns out that Bayes Theorem is needed, after all.

Comment: @karl means we have to find $P(\frac{A}{B})=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

Comment: @jacky I'm not sure what you mean by that. What does $P(\frac AB)$ mean to you? (Do you mean $P(A|B)$?) Can you say how you think that relates to this problem? What are $A$ and $B$ in this case?

Comment: You might want to review [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: There are 3 February 29's in the set.  There are $10*11+3 = 113$ months with a 29th day.

Comment: @DougM But the answer isn't $\frac3{113}$, because not all of those "29th" dates are equally likely to be selected. Feb. 29, 2020 is more likely than Dec. 29, 2020 by a factor of $\frac{1/29}{1/31}$.

Comment: @Karl  All 29th days are equally likely.  In 2020 with 12 months of at least 29 days, $P(\text{February}|29th) = P(29th|\text{February})\frac {P(\text{February})}{P(29th)} = \frac {1}{29}\frac {\frac {29}{366}}{\frac {12}{366}} = \frac {1}{12}$

Comment: @DougM That would be true if we were selecting a date uniformly at random from the whole range, making long months slightly more likely than short months. But in this problem, we first select a month uniformly at random and then select a day at random from that month. The result is that any given date in a short month is slightly more likely than a given date in a long month.

Comment: @Karl thanks, I missed that nuance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can classify all of the possible "29th" dates as follows:

- Feb 29ths. The probability of selecting any given one of these (e.g. Feb. 29, 2020) is $\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{29}$, and there are 3 of them (2012, 2016, 2020).
- The 29th of a 31-day month. The probability of picking any given one of these (e.g. Jan. 29, 2020) is $\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{31}$, and there are $10\cdot7$ of them (in Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec of each year).
- The 29th of a 30-day month. The probability of picking any given one of these (e.g. Apr. 29, 2020) is $\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{30}$, and there are $10\cdot4$ of them (in Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov of each year).

Therefore, the probability that we select a 29th is $3\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{29}+70\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{31}+40\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{30}$.

The probability that we select a **February** 29th is just the first term: $3\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{29}$.

So *given* that a 29th was selected, the [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) that February was selected is the ratio of these:

$$\frac{3\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{29}}{3\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{29}+70\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{31}+40\times\frac1{10}\frac1{12}\frac1{30}}
$$

Notice that the factors of $\frac1{10}\frac1{12}$ all cancel out, so this simplifies to

$$\frac{\frac3{29}}{\frac3{29}+\frac{70}{31}+\frac{40}{30}}$$

which is equal to $\frac{279}{9965}$.

Comment: Since it is *given* that the chosen day is $29^{th}$, why should we take into account varying days in months ? For any given year and month, the probability of choosing $29{th}$ should be $1$ no ?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing

Comment: the probability seems 3/113 to me

Comment: Say I flip a fair coin to choose between a 6-sided die and a 100-sided die. Given that I then roll a 1, what's the probability that I flipped heads? Is it $\frac12$ because "the reduced sample space" is just two 1s? No—knowing that I got a 1 gives you evidence in favor of the 6-sided die; Bayes' theorem gives the correct answer $P(D6|1)=\frac{\frac12\frac16}{\frac12\frac16+\frac12\frac1{100}}=\frac{50}{53}$. In the same way, knowing that a 29th was selected gives you (slight) evidence in favor of Feb 2020 over Dec 2020, so the conditional distribution over months is no longer uniform.

Comment: @Karl: I understand, (+1)